# How do I insert a random value into mysql?

Tags: mysql, random, insert

It looks like RAND is what I need but I'm having a bit of trouble understanding how it works.

I need to insert a random number between 60 and 120 into a couple thousand rows.  Table name is: listing and the column name is: hits

Could you please help?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

To make a random integer between 60 and 120, you need to do a bit of arithmetic with the results of `RAND()`, which produces only floating point values:

```
SELECT FLOOR(60 + RAND() * 61);
```

So what's going on here:

`RAND()` will produce a value like `0.847269199`.  We multiply that by 61, which gives us the value 51.83615194.  We add 60, since  that's your desired offset above zero (111.83615194). `FLOOR()` rounds the whole thing down to the nearest whole number.  Finally, you have 111.

To do this over a few thousand existing rows:

```
UPDATE table SET randcolumn = FLOOR(60 + RAND() * 61) WHERE (<some condition if necessary>);
```

See [the MySQL docs on `RAND()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand) for more examples.

**Note** I think I have the arithmetic right, but if you get values of 59 or 121 outside the expected range, change the `+60` up or down accordingly.

Comment: That will only produce numbers in [0;120) - you need to multiply by 61.

Comment: @emboss It produced [60:119], not [0:120], but you're correct about the 61 multiplier

Comment: Thanks all.  I had to read that about 3X to understand it but I got it.. and the query worked great!

Answer (score 6):

Here is how to get the random number in a range.  The following can bit a bit ambiguous simply because the 61 is actually your max value (120) minus your min value (60) + 1 to get inclusive results.

```
SELECT FLOOR(60 + (RAND() * 61));

SELECT FLOOR(MIN_Value + (RAND() * (MAX_Value - MIN_Value) + 1);
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE X SET C = FLOOR(61 * RAND() + 60) WHERE ...;
```

to get a number between 60 and 120 (including 60 and 120);

`RAND()` creates a number in the interval [0;1) (that is excluding 1). So 61 * RAND() yields a number in [0, 61). 61 * RAND() + 60 is in [60;121) By rounding down you ensure that your number is indeed in [60;120].

Answer (score 0):

When I faced this kind of issue, I tried manual, but I have over 500 lines,
I logically brought a trick which helped me, because if you run RAND on query,
you might end up getting error report due to Duplicates, OR PRIMARY KEY issue, especially if that column is a `PRIMARY KEY` and `AUTO INCREMENT`.

1. **Firstly -** I renamed the column in question, **e.g.** mine was ID -> IDS
2. **Secondly -** I created another column and Called it ID
3. **Thirdly -** I RAN this code

> UPDATE history SET id = FLOOR( 217 + RAND( ) *2161 )

This created a random numbers automatically, later i deleted the renamed IDS colume

credit FROM MICHAEL.
Thank you